# Is it possible to create content and link it to an existing menu item?

Tags: 7, routes

I have a menu tree with links all directing to 'front'.

On creating content I don't want to create a new menu item but want to have an extra option under the Menu settings saying 'Add content to existing menu item'.

What is the best way to achieve this or is there a module available that handles this situation (D7)?

Comment: Do you mean you want to overwrite the URL of the existing menu item with the new content's URL? And what is the context for doing this?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have to write a custom module. [This](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/24545/what-would-be-the-correct-way-of-adding-a-link-to-existing-path-into-admin-menu) may be a similar situation.

Comment: I do not want to add a link because the links are allready there so both questions have nothing in common. I think I would be more something like a hook_form_alter on the node/add forms but I'm a little lost on how to approach the menu tree.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need just go to admin panel -> Structure -> Menus. Find the menu you want to add the link to and and hit "List links" Then find the menu item you want to link content to and hit "edit", and change it's url from  to the url of corresponding content.

Comment: I want to link to an existing menu item on the node/add form before saving the node instead of searching in the menus after saving the new node.

Answer (score 1):

Default Drupal behavior allows you to create a new link, under a menu tree item of your choice, at the time of saving a node, as below.
[image: adding node menu link at time of node creation]

Have I understood right? - What you want to do is, be able to select a menu tree item, just like in the above image, but not have to enter title and description etc. You don't want new menu item created, but use the existing one, and have its path value changed from `front` to the path of the new node?

^ If that is the case, you have to create a quick custom module to do so. A good idea would be to form alter (the fields, the submission behavior) the same form in the image above. That way you do not have to code the menu tree loading and selecting parts etc.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is the [Menu editor](https://drupal.org/project/menu_editor) module. Make sure you enable the `me_node_creation` submodule.

You create the menu links as placeholders, with `<new>` as the link path. Then on visiting any such item, you get to a page that allows you to create a real node attached to this menu link.